# how to set the width of a particular TD to its content width?

Tags: html, css

I need to set the width of a particular TD element in a table to its content width, but this content is variable due to dynamic data loaded from a database.

This is what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.block {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: monospace;
        }
        .debug1 {
            border: solid blue 1px;
        }
        .debug2 {
            border: solid red 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 600px; border: solid black 1px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class=debug1 style="text-align: right;">
                    &#x25C4;
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="block debug2">700000</div>
                    <div class="block debug2">700001</div>
                    <div class="block debug2">700002</div>
                </td>
                <td class=debug1>
                    &#x25BA;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wm592qj2/

And this is what I want:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.block {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: monospace;
        }
        .debug1 {
            border: solid blue 1px;
        }
        .debug2 {
            border: solid red 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 600px; border: solid black 1px; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class=debug1 style="width: 200px; text-align: right;">
                    &#x25C4;
                </td>
                <td style="width: 160px; border: solid cyan 1px; text-align: center;">
                    <div class="block debug2">700000</div>
                    <div class="block debug2">700001</div>
                    <div class="block debug2">700002</div>
                </td>
                <td class=debug1 style="width: 200px;">
                    &#x25BA;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yj9oy9gs/

Recap:

- I want the list of records (class `block`) to be displayed in the center, so the TD element must have its width set to the width of its content, but the content is variable al the time (it may have 3 divs, or it may have 10 divs)
- I want the Next and Previous buttons to be adjacent to the last and first divs (records, i.e class `block`). I am implementing a record browser so it must look nice.

Note that the second fiddle has fixed widths, that's why it works, but I have dynamic width for the second TD element (central part of the table).

So, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make your `table` behave like a `flex` , add theses to you `table` :

```
display:flex; 
flex-direction:column; 
align-items: center;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div.block {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: monospace;
    }
    
    .debug1 {
      border: solid blue 1px;
    }
    
    .debug2 {
      border: solid red 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items: center; width: 600px; border: solid black 1px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class=debug1 style="text-align: right;">
          &#x25C4;
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="block debug2">700000</div>
          <div class="block debug2">700001</div>
          <div class="block debug2">700002</div>          
        </td>
        <td class=debug1>
          &#x25BA;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wow! this is what I exactly needed. Didn't knew about `flexbox` until today, and it is really cool, Building layouts in HTML sucks , but flex makes it so easy.

Comment: now I have to rewrite all my code to use `flex` containers everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the width and height with the max attribute.

I put 100px as an example but you can put the desired values.

```css
.block{
  max-width:100px;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  div.block {
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: monospace;
  }
  .debug1 {
   border: solid blue 1px;
  }
  .debug2 {
   border: solid red 1px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <table style="width: 600px; border: solid black 1px;">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class=debug1 style="text-align: right;">
     &#x25C4;
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
     <div class="block debug2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
     <div class="block debug2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
     <div class="block debug2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </td>
    <td class=debug1>
     &#x25BA;
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```